# How to implement app purchase in Android app?

Tags: android, android-billing

There is a free android app, but user purchases additional service packages in the app for 3,6 months or a year.

As far as I understood, I need to keep variable, which is false by default and after launch I make QueryPurchases (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases) and watch if some package is purchased and date of purchase. If period has not passed (3-6-12 months) -> then this variable is set to true.

What I mean is variable is not kept in the app, but defined after launch or while app is working, and based on it we limit user functions

Am I going right way?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I created products and implemented purchase in the app.

Comment: onProductPurchased callback we receive after purchase. Orders are displayed in merchant account